# https old url to new https url in same website

Tags: php, .htaccess, ssl, opencart

I have a open cart website. with ssl certificate and I want to redirect my 
https: /categeory.html to https: /category

and website have already this url https:/category
 but my website back link that we have created on other website is 
https:/category.html.

I have already apply so many code in htaccess.

please help.

Comment: I think you've forgotten to add your code...

Comment: Redirect 301 ^/anarkali-suits.html https://www.crazora.com/anarkali-suits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `RedirectMatch`

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^.]+)\.html$ https://example.com/$1
```

Comment: @Aarif if the answer has solved your problem ,you can accept it so that it doesnt show up in unanswered ones.

Comment: thank you sir yes i solved my problem and accept it [done ]